# How to write Video Cutter (native trimmer)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, ffmpeg, video-editing

I want to write a Video Cutter for React Native. The goal is to choose the time interval from the video and cut it out. For example: 1 minute cut out of 10 minute video. Also I'll be able to rewind the video according to the frames.What is the correct way to solve this problem?

I want to write it myself and not use any Package.

Should I write it separately? for Android - Java and iOS -swift? Which is the good way?

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a **Video Cutter** library for React Native whether it's for iOS (Objective-C/Swift) or Android (Java/Kotlin), you need to use Native Modules.

React Native is designed such that it is possible for you to write real native code and have access to the full power of the platform. This is a more advanced feature however, it is essential that it exists. If React Native doesn't support a native feature that you need, you should be able to build it yourself. This is the case of a **Video Cutter**.

If you can do it for Android, or iOS you can do it for React Native.

- [iOS Native Modules Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)
- [Android Native Modules Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android)

Focusing more on the **Video Cutter**, I have [this android project](https://github.com/iknow4/Android-Video-Trimmer) that could help you develop the library. Check out [trim folder](https://github.com/iknow4/Android-Video-Trimmer/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/iknow/android/features/trim) inside the project. This could help you to recreate and elaborate something similar.

There is also this library [react-native-video-processing](https://github.com/shahen94/react-native-video-processing) that is implemented in both [iOS](https://github.com/shahen94/react-native-video-processing/tree/master/ios) and [Android](https://github.com/shahen94/react-native-video-processing/tree/master/android). You can check the code out and do something similar.